MultiLineString displaced at some zoom level in QGIS
I have a segment of a MultiLineString well displayed on zoom level 1:2100:

but a lower level like 1:1050 and PDF exports, some segments are displaced:

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

On the second image, you can see the segment at the right place in the first image is displaced with strange U shape. I don't know how to explain better the issue

I think its clear what you are asking, but the QGIS Version and eventually a single test MultiLineString could help us reproducing the issue and looking for a cause. Maybe it is also just a bug, so if its works fine on older versions consider raising a bug report on the QGIS github site.

Check that your layer has no geometry error (use the "Check validity" processing tool or the Check Geometry core plugin from the vector menu), most of rendering problem are caused by geometry error. If the option is activated you may also try to uncheck the "Simplify Geometry" in the Rendering tab of the Layer properties.

I checked the Vector/Geometry Tools/Check Validity : no invalid/error
I tried to uncheck Layer Properties/Rendering/Simplify Geometry : don't change anything. If you have other ideas, they are welcome ;) THanks

If you bring the layer into a new project without any symbology changes, and look at it at those scales does it show issues?  If not can you then change the symbology and have it work, including finally applying the same symbology as in your original?   Are you using snapping and what are the settings?

I used the original symbology, no changes. I was just exporting the map with a layout
